# small team git workflow

Tags: git, github

I want to ask if the following workflow is correct!
It is referring to a small private team.
There is a master branch where no one merges there ( except the maintainer ),
a development branch and individual branches for every user. So,every user will push to development branch.

So:

```
* clone the repo to your local machine
  git clone https://github.com/username/project.git

* cd project

* git remote add upstream https://github.com/group/project.git

* git checkout userbranch 
* git add files
  git commit -m ".."

* git push origin userbranch ( I am not sure if this step is necessary since I 

* Merge into development and push your work to development
  git checkout development
  git merge --no-ff userbranch
  git push origin development

* Update local master to apply changes from master to the local  repository.
  git checkout userbranch  ( or checkout local master? )
  git fetch upstream
  git merge upstream/development

* git push origin development
```

I am not sure if all the sequence is right (I don't want to make any mistakes!). Also, I am not sure about the steps where I say `Update local master to apply changes from master to the local  repository` and `Merge into development and push your work to development` if they work as expected.

And at the last step do I have to checkout on my branch or my local master?

And finally , (if the above is correct ) at which point do I fetch and merge from master branch?Generally,how can I combine master and development branches?

Answer (score 3):

Your question should involve description of your delivery and development process, and then you could decide which branches you need to maintain.

I assume a classical set-up. You have a main development branch - where everything is developed by default, and a release branch, which is what you are preparing to publish as a release to customers.

For a default development branch is better to use `master` branch, as it is default branch, so developers could work on it straight away. For releases create a branch `release`. The workflow for a developer is following:

1. git clone https://github.com/username/project.git
2. cd project
3. git add files/git commit
4. git pull, git push
5. go to 3.

For a release manager during release:

1. git checkout release
2. git merge master
3. git tag v1.2.3.4
4. git push && git push --tags

"Userbranches" will be local branches in dev's clones (or in forks), so usually you don't need to do anything special about it, no special names. It's easier when branch names match.

This is the very basic scenario, if you need some more options, e.g. doing hotfixes or feature branches, you could build all of it on top of this base.

If you need a code-review (only a designated person could merge code from devs into master), then you need forks. The forks in github are for pull-requests. So, user pushes his work into a fork and sends a pull request to the designated person.

Comment: :Thanks for the answer but I was hoping for someone to use my approach and correct me and answer to my questions.

Comment: @George "Your question should involve description of your delivery and development process, and then you could decide which branches you need to maintain." :)

Comment: @George If you not sure what exactly do you need, just start with the base I described and then ask questions how to solve particular issues if you have any. Your approach could be correct (there are dozens correct workflows!), but looks overcomplicated for "a small private team".

Comment: As I said , everyuser will develop on his own branch.Then every user pushes changes to development branch and then ( maybe only one or two users or everyone (we haven't decided yet) ) pushes to master.So, I want to be able to push to development branch and to fetch and merge from development and from master branches.And I am not sure which comes first and if the steps I described are correct.Thank you.

Comment: @George In this case you could just follow github workflow. A "master" branch in a dev's fork is already dev's branch. Each dev could push into their fork's master. After the push, they should raise a pull request via github web-interface, so the main repo maintainer (i.e. project owner) will accept the pull requests merging the changes into main master branch. See here https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/

Comment: @kan:We decided not to fork just clone.My main concern is the pulling and merging from/to development branch and then the same for master.(Can I ask you ,now that I am using only clone of the project, I don't need to run `git add upstream ...` ?Right?Because I have already the project

Comment: `upstream` or `origin` just a user-friendly names for remote repo urls. Check what you have and change/delete what you don't want to have (see `git help remote` for details how). `origin` name is automatically added during clone. If you don't want forks, it's easier to do that I originally described with master/release. It would be more difficult to handle if everyone will push/pull from/to both branches.